# i have exception error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll Incorrect syntax near 'ID'."

Tags: c#, sql, .net

This is my code and it shows this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Incorrect syntax near 'ID'.

Please help me with this code:

```
public void count_accno()
   {
       conn.Open();
       string str =  "SELECT MAX(Category ID) FROM Category";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
       SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while(dr.Read())
       {
           textBox1.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
       }
       int i = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
       i= i + 1;
       textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
       conn.Close();
       dr.Close();
   }
```

Comment: column name seems to be invalid

Comment: `Category ID` is *not a valid identifie*r, do you mean `Category_ID` or say, `[Category ID]`? Or two fields: `Max(Category), Max(ID)`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Category ID` is **not** a *valid identifier* and so you have the exception. Here we have three typical corrections for you to chose from:

1. *Validate* field name `Category ID` and put its correct version, say, `Category_ID`, `CategoryID`
2. *Escape*: `Category ID` and have a valid name with *space*: `[Category ID]`
3. Have *two* fields: `SELECT Max(Category), Max(ID) FROM Category`

**Code:**

```
   public void count_accno() {
     //TODO: instead of opening existing connection, create a new one  
     conn.Open();

     try { 
       string str = 
         @"SELECT MAX([Category ID]) -- wild guess: escapement
             FROM Category"; 

       //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn)) {
         //TODO: Have a look at ExecuteScalar
         using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
           //DONE: we want 1st record only (while is not wanted here)

           // The query will return 1 record; 
           // thus we, probably want to check for `Null` not for `dr.Read`:
           if (dr.Read() && !dr.IsDBNull(0)) {
             textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]) + 1).ToString();
           }
           else {
             // Table is empty
           }
         }
       }
     }
     finally {
       // finally: rain or shine close the connection
       conn.Close();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MAX` function requires 1 argument.
You are calling MAX with two arguments: `Category` and `ID`.